# Dart language standard installation directory?

Tags: dart

Is there a standard or recommended installation directory for the Dart language?  If so, I would like to know what it is for both Windows and Mac.  I searched online on dartlang.org, Google, and StackOverflow.  For Mac specifically, I have seen many programming languages installed under /Library.

I believe the standard workspace for Dart projects is ~/dart.  When you download the Dart language, you are given a /dart folder containing the Editor, SDK, Chromium with Dart VM installed, and some extras.  I am wondering what the standard location for this folder is.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard workspace directory for Dart projects is like you wrote `~/dart` in Linux (don't know about other OS).

The standard installation directory is depending on conventions of your OS than the Dart language.
You should have an environment variable `DART_SDK` pointing to the `dart-sdk` subdirectory of the installation directory and include the `DART_SDK/bin` in your path.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that the standard installation directory is a convention of the OS, rather than the language. I had not realized this at the time that I posted the question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

On MAC, just drop the directory on App directory, then in terminal you put : "export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/dart/dart-sdk/bin"